# How to set and get values for Composite primary keys and other fields in jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

> This is my Entity class

```
 @EmbeddedId

private AuthorWorkPKEmbedded embeddedId;

@Column(name = "ColumnA")
private String ColumnA;

public AuthorWorkPKEmbedded getEmbeddedId() {
    return embeddedId;
}

public void setEmbeddedId(AuthorWorkPKEmbedded embeddedId) {
    this.embeddedId = embeddedId;
}

public String getColumnA() {
    return ColumnA;
}

public void setColumnA(String ColumnA) {
    this.ColumnA = ColumnA;
}



public AuthorWorkEmbedded() {
}

public AuthorWorkEmbedded(BigInteger bookId,BigInteger authorId) {
    this.embeddedId = new AuthorWorkPKEmbedded(bookId, authorId);
}
```

> This is my Embeddable class

```
 @Embeddable
@Column(name = "bookId", nullable = false)
private BigInteger bookId;

@Column(name = "authorId", nullable = false)
private BigInteger authorId;

public AuthorWorkPKEmbedded() {
}

public AuthorWorkPKEmbedded(BigInteger bookId, BigInteger authorId) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
    this.authorId = authorId;
}

public BigInteger getBookId() {
    return bookId;
}

public void setBookId(BigInteger bookId) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
}

public BigInteger getAuthorId() {
    return authorId;
}

public void setAuthorId(BigInteger authorId) {
    this.authorId = authorId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return bookId.hashCode() + authorId.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof AuthorWorkPKEmbedded)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
   AuthorWorkEmbedded pk=(AuthorWorkEmbedded) obj;
   return (((bookId==((AuthorWorkPKEmbedded)obj).getBookId()))
           &&((authorId==((AuthorWorkPKEmbedded)obj).getAuthorId())));
}
```

> This is my main class
>   how set the composite values and why cant we use generatedvalue for autoincrement purpose and how to retrieve the values from the the database and one more thing where to declare other fields in Entity class or embeddable class and if not how to set and get the values from these 2 classes(entity and embeddable)

```
 EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
        AuthorWorkPKEmbedded author = new AuthorWorkPKEmbedded();
        author.setBookId(BigInteger.ONE);
        author.setAuthorId(BigInteger.ONE);

        AuthorWorkEmbedded a1=new AuthorWorkEmbedded();
        a1.setEmbeddedId(author);
        a1.setColumnA("Pirates of carrabian");

        boolean successful = false;
        try {
            em.persist(author);
            successful = true;
        } finally {
            if (successful) {
                entr.commit();
            } else {
                entr.rollback();
            }
        }
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("AuthorWork.findAll");
        List authorList = query.getResultList();
        Iterator authorIterator = authorList.iterator();
        while (authorIterator.hasNext()) {
            author = (AuthorWorkPKEmbedded) authorIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Book Id " + author.getBookId() + " " + "Author" + author.getAuthorId() + "");
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getters and setters for embeddedId .

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("AuthorWork.findAll");
        List authorList = query.getResultList();
        Iterator authorIterator = authorList.iterator();
        while (authorIterator.hasNext()) {
            author = (AuthorWorkEmbedded) authorIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Book Id " + author.setEmbeddedId().getBookId() + " " + "Author" + author.getEmbeddedId().getAuthorId() + "");
            System.out.println(""+author.getColumnA());
        }
```

Comment: :i have set and get in entity class

Comment: As you have asked declare other fields in the AuthorWorkEmbedded  class. Only PK fileds should be present in @Embeddable class.

Comment: :author.setEmbeddedId().getBookId() i am not able to use setembbeddedid since it is entity class .can u show me how to proceed

Comment: sorry ..As you set before saving is correct.Only while getting values of database use System.out.println("Book Id " + author.getEmbeddedId().getBookId() + " " + "Author" + author.getEmbeddedId().getAuthorId() + ""); System.out.println(""+author.getColumnA());  persist the value of em.persist(a1);

Comment: you should save the entity class and not the embeddable class.And fetch values of the saved entity class .

Comment: :i am getting some problem The abstract schema type 'AuthorWork' is unknown for this named query                           The abstract schema type 'AuthorWork' is unknown                        @Table(name = "AUTHOR_WORK")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AuthorWork.findAll",query="SELECT a FROM AuthorWork a")
})

Comment: :some problem in namedquery

Comment: In named query "select a from AuthorWorkEmbedded a" author = (AuthorWorkEmbedded) authorIterator.next();

Comment: :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.key.AuthorWorkPKEmbedded@2 is not a known entity type.

Comment: Tell the entity class name and Embeddable class name

Comment: entity class name is AuthorWorkEmbedded and embeddable class name is AuthorWorkPKEmbedded  and i have made few changes                       AuthorWorkPKEmbedded author = new AuthorWorkPKEmbedded(); author.setBookId(BigInteger.ONE);
author.setAuthorId(BigInteger.ONE);
AuthorWorkEmbedded a1=new AuthorWorkEmbedded(); a1.setEmbeddedId(author);
a1.setColumnA("Pirates of carrabian");    a1 = (AuthorWorkEmbedded) authorIterator.next();
System.out.println("Book Id " + a1.getEmbeddedId().getBookId() + " " + "Author" + a1.getEmbeddedId().getAuthorId() + "" +a1.getColumnA());

Comment: the table is getting created but the values are not able to set in database is this correct author.setAuthorId(BigInteger.ONE)

Comment: yes . correct .have u persisted em.persist(a1);     Use @Transactional in the class where you are going to run as mainclass to persist.  Comment the code below which is used to get values from database. first save and then can be fetched easily

Comment: i have made changes like  AuthorWorkEmbedded a1=new AuthorWorkEmbedded();
  em.persist(a1);
            a1.setEmbeddedId(author);
            a1.setColumnA("Pirates of carrabian"); and where to use @transactional in entity class or embeddable class